# проблема POST и FancyBox

Tags: php, fancybox

Есть форма. Она всё отправляет, всё работает отлично.
Но вот решил я засунуть форму в FancyBox и она перестала работать, т.е. на `POST` ни чего не отправляет и не показывает окошко которое, если `POST` сработало отрисовывается.
Кто сталкивался? Как подправить?

---

Если прописывать в форме `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"`, то после нажатия кнопки "отправить", форма разворачивается на весь экран, как обычная страница.

Comment: Обычно, в вопросе, программисты оставляют код, который они писали и с которым проблемы..... А также указывают версию программ, с которыми работают....например какой версии `fancybox`? А какой код вы пишите, который не работает так, как надо?

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему через тип iframe от FancyBox